# Content Resolver SQLite refresh data after operation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider, reload

My problem is that I do content resolver operations (CRUD) and my local Sqlite data base gets the changes but they do not show/refresh those changes in my TEXTVIEW, in here I'm not talking about refreshing a listview/recyclerview with adapters like 100% of the questions in here I'm just talking about a simple text view which fetch information from the local database so in here I'm not using adapters or recycler views (not yet).
I've tried:

- Use the database helper constructor after a new content resolver operation but is not working.
- use the close() after a content provider operation.
- cResolver.notifyChange() after applying a batch of operations.
- I've tried to use the LoaderManager but it appears that is only useful for adapters with the swapcursor.

How do I know my CRUD ops are working? if I restart my app the changes are there. Any help in the rigth directions will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Finally made it!, I implemented a content observer and in the onChange() I simply requery my database by filling all the need it textviews to be filled with a simple query/cursor and moveToFirst()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any change on your database is reflected only on your database. If you need to update a text view after the change, you need to handle that the change have been made and update your view.
An alternative to update your view and data after persisting it to a database is using the [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html) or any observable.

Comment: I see, sounds like the way to go but could you share an example with CRUD operations?

Comment: Thanks for your respose, I managed to implement am observer and all of its methods, now I have the problem of not knowing how to refresh my cursor?